# DbMigrator not rolling back

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an custom `IDatabaseInitializer` in Entity Framework 6 and noticed strange thing. When calling `DbMigrator.Update` method, if the migration fails the transaction, it is not rolled back thus leaving database in inconsistent state where you can no longer downgrade.

Here is the migration code i am using:

```
var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);

var pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();

if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
{
    migrator.Update();
}
```

Should I simply do something like this:

```
using (var trx = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    try
    {
        var migrator = new DbMigrator(_configuration);

        var pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();

        if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
        {
            migrator.Update();
        }
    trx.Commit();
    }catch
    {
        trx.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

As I understand this should work, just cant figure why `DbMigrator` doesn't do this internally.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that occurs due to database engines such as MYSQL i was using not supporting transactional ALTER and would do implicit commit.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html